# Converting SQL query that uses CASE WHEN conditions to construct a column to python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, join

**Input:**

base_table:

| year | category | country | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | English | null | 1 |
| 2023 | English | null | 2 |
| 2022 | English | US | 1 |
| 2023 | Science | null | 2 |

inter_table:

| year | country | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | US | 100 |
| 2023 | US | 400 |
| 2022 | Europe | 300 |
| 2023 | Europe | 200 |

**Output:**

| year | category | country | class | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | English | null | 1 | 500 |
| 2023 | English | null | 2 | null |
| 2022 | English | US | 1 | 100 |
| 2023 | Science | null | 2 | null |

Aim: Above are the input and output tables. Aim is to convert the below sql code to Python:

```sql
select a.year, a.category, a.country, a.class,
case when a.country is null and category='English'
then case 
     when class = 1 then (select amount*5 from inter_table b where country='US' and b.year=a.year)
     when class = 2 then case when (select amount from inter_table b where a.country=b.country and  b.year=a.year) is not null 
     then (select sum(amount)*5 from inter_table b where country='US' and b.year=a.year) else null end 
end else amount end new_col
from base_table a
left join inter_table b
on a.year=b.year and a.country=b.country;
```

The above sql code is a simple select few columns along with creation of a new column called `new_col`.

This sql takes input tables base table & inter table and output is also provided above. I'm trying to convert this code in sql to python.

What I tried is using `pd.merge()` to join base & inter table and where I'm stuck is on creation of the `new_col` column which involves multiple case when conditions.

Comment: @RavenSmith it's not clear how you would apply filters for multiple countries, can you expand the question to include a query which uses two countries instead of only the US?

Answer (score 1):

Your PostgreSQL query can be reduced of its multiple subqueries by using the joined `inter_table` and an aggregated version of `inter_table`:

```sql
with us_agg as (
   select country, year, sum(amount) as amount
   from inter_table b 
   where country='US'
   group by country, year
)

select 
    t.year, t.category, t.country, t.class,
    case 
       when t.country is null and t.category='English'
       then case 
               when t.class = 1 then us_agg.amount*5
               when t.class = 2 then 
                  case 
                     when i.amount is not null then us_agg.amount*5
                  end 
            end
       else i.amount
    end new_col
from base_table t
left join inter_table i
  on t.year = i.year and t.country = i.country
left join us_agg 
  on t.year = us_agg.year;
```

From there you can probably flatten the nested `case` statements:

```sql
    case 
       when t.country is null and t.category='English' and t.class = 1
       then us_agg.amount*5
       when t.country is null and t.category='English' and t.class = 2 and i.amount is not null
       then us_agg.amount*5
       else i.amount
    end new_col
```

<kbd>[**Online Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/vTEo722_)</kbd>

Then, in pandas after two merges (regular level, `inter_table` and aggregated `inter_table`), use [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for the conditional logic for new column:

```py
us_agg = (
    inter_table.query("country == 'US'")
        .groupby(["year"]).agg(us_amount = ("amount", "sum"))
)

final_df = (
    base_table.merge(inter_table, on=["country", "year"], how="left", suffixes=["", "_"])
        .merge(us_agg, on=["year"], how="left", suffixes=["", "_agg"])
)

conds = [
    (
        final_df["country"].isna() & final_df["category"].eq('English') & 
        final_df["class"].eq(1)
    ),
    (
        final_df["country"].isna() & final_df["category"].eq('English') & 
        final_df["class"].eq(2) & final_df["amount"].notnull()
    )
]

vals = [final_df["us_amount"].mul(5), final_df["us_amount"].mul(5)]

final_df["new_col"] = np.select(conds, vals, default = final_df["amount"])
```

**NOTE**: Above is not tested on actual data. Actual columns and conditional logic may need adjustment.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, I tried to replicate your solution, but the sql query you had shared does not fetch the same result, you can compare the results in the db-fiddle here https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=JQkNGn4Hom, please let me know what other modifications we need to make to the code

Comment: I can't access that fiddle. At the time of writing this solution, I had no data to test against. Please use the high-level approach to simplify `case` statements and then translate to pandas with `numpy` methods. As noted, you may have to adjust logic as needed. Only you know and have your actual data. That SQL was admittedly a tough read to translate.

Comment: Hi @Parfait, I did not test in actual data, but even in given data in stack overflow, it is not giving the expected output as mentioned in question

Comment: Using example data, I have adjusted my solution with a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vTEo722_) showing rewritten SQL queries now match original.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, one challenge is I have many such filters for country = 'US' where you have added that as CTE, so if I have 7 country filters, then it would be 7 CTEs right? so it there a more simplified way to not specify that where country='US' in CTE? Please let me know

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` (or add countries to it with `IN`) of CTE, then left join it to  main query by `country` and `year`. Then add `CASE WHEN` statements to handle the 7 countries.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's a third-party library that builds on pandas called `pandasql` which can run a SQL query using dataframes defined in your local environment. It can be using pip etc. Just pass off your SQL query as a string to `pandasql.sqldf` and it spits out the corresponding output.

```py
!pip install pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf

base_table = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2023, 2022, 2023],
    'category': ['English', 'English', 'English', 'Science'],
    'country': [float('nan'), float('nan'), 'US', float('nan')],
    'class': [1, 2, 1, 2]})

inter_table = pd.DataFrame({
    'year': [2022, 2023, 2022, 2023],
    'country': ['US', 'US', 'Europe', 'Europe'],
    'amount': [100, 400, 300, 200]})

output = sqldf("""
select a.year, a.category, a.country, a.class,
case when a.country is null and category='English'
then case 
     when class = 1 then (select amount*5 from inter_table b where country='US' and b.year=a.year)
     when class = 2 then case when (select amount from inter_table b where a.country=b.country and  b.year=a.year) is not null 
     then (select sum(amount)*5 from inter_table b where country='US' and b.year=a.year) else null end 
end else amount end new_col
from base_table a
left join inter_table b
on a.year=b.year and a.country=b.country;
""")
```

With that being said, if you want to convert the SQL syntax into pandas syntax, we can first merge, and then replace `amount` values in the merged frame using boolean conditions that corresponds to the CASE WHEN cases.

```py
# left-merge the frames on year and country
output = base_table.merge(inter_table, on=['year', 'country'], how='left')
# construct the outer condition of CASE WHEN
base_msk = output['country'].isna() & output['category'].eq('English')
# construct the condition for CLASS=1
msk1 = base_msk & output['class'].eq(1)
# the values to assign when CASE=1
case1 = output.query("country == 'US'").groupby('year')['amount'].mean()*5
# construct the condition for CASE=2
msk2 = base_msk & output['class'].eq(2)
# assign values when CLASS=1
output.loc[msk1, 'amount'] = output.loc[msk1, 'year'].map(case1)
# assign values when CLASS=2
output['amount'] = output['amount'].mask(msk2)
# rename `amount` column
output.rename(columns={'amount': 'new_col'}, inplace=True)
```

Using the sample in the OP, we get the expected output:

```
   year category country  class  new_col
0  2022  English     NaN      1    500.0
1  2023  English     NaN      2      NaN
2  2022  English      US      1    100.0
3  2023  Science     NaN      2      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each record of your Pandas dataframe and reassign the value based on your conditional logic. Looping is not very efficient for very large dataframes but I use it often for smaller ones

```
us_value = output[output['country'] == 'US'].new_col

for i in output.index:
    country = output.at[i, 'country']
    category = output.at[i, 'category']
    classval = output.at[i, 'class']
    
    if (country == 'null') & (category == 'English'):
        if classval == 1:
            output.at[i, 'new_col'] = us_value*5
```

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use [pandas apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on each row and assign its output to your final dataFrame like this:

```
base_table["new_col"] = base_table.apply(return_new_col_value, 
                        axis=1, additional_table=inter_table)
```

The function passed to apply could look something likes this then:

```
def return_new_col_value(row, additional_table):
    if row["class"] == 1:
        #  calculate some value based on additional_table
    elif row["class"] == 2:
        # perform different calculation
    else:
        # perform different calculation 2
```

This option would pass the inter_table as an additional argument to the row wise function so you can perform the filtering (i.e. the sql where clauses) and aggregation (i.e. the sql sum) on inter_table needed for your calculations.

Comment: Avoid `apply` loops for conditional logic. Use vectorized operations such as `numpy.where` or `numpy.select`.